# How to float two divs above an image?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs and two images in one div. The images are stacked. The div they are inside is relative and the images and the two divs are absolute. Now I want to float one div on the right side but it didn't work .
Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2vrq243v/2/

```css
#newsline {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#newsline a img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 360px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px 5% 20px 5%;
}

.move {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.move:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.move p {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  color: rgb(250, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-size: 250%;
  background-color: none;
}

.move p:hover {
  color: darkslategrey;
}

.next {
  float: right;
}

.previous {
  margin-left: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsline">
  <div class="move next">
    <p>⮚</p>
  </div>
  <div class="move previous">
    <p>⮘</p>
  </div>
  <a href=""><img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/8ccb4ec4225b290726ae9be975220ff4.jpg" id="img1"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Awesome-Wallpaper.jpg" id="img2"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: no need really to use margin nor float with absolute elements, coordonates are made for that purpose. https://jsfiddle.net/2vrq243v/6/ see SirExotic's answeer

Comment: oh yeah thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this? You can adjust the position of the two `div`s using the `left` and `right` property, this is possible because they have the `position: absolute`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2vrq243v/7/)

```
.next {
  right: 6%;
}

.previous {
  left: 6%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the proper positioning of controls use:

```
.next {     
 right: 0;
 margin-right: 6%
};

.previous {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 6%;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute` is redundant because it is already applied on `.move`, and `margin-right` can be applied to `right` as 6%.

Comment: Agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey whenever you are using a position in css use left, right instead of float left or right. Your Problem can be solved by following code:

```
.next {
    right: 55px;
}
```

Remove float:right; use right and give the required value

Comment: when do i use float then ? I thought it was for this purpose

Comment: The above link provided by @AlexandreAimbiré will help you and its because Absolutely positioned elements ignores the float property!